# Hiding/Removing part of a curve in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics, curve

I'd like when plotting a curve from a set of data, hiding parts that meet some conditions, for example, hiding everything with a value > 10 on the y axis.

I can't just set the value to 0 or to a really high number and just use xlim or ylim since the moment I plot with a line type, I will have a vertical line and I don't want that.

```r
x <- seq(from=-50,to=50,by=0.1)
#I'd like every part of the curve above 1000 to disappear for example
y<--x^2+2500
plot(x,y,type="l")
y[y>1000]<-0
#this will create two vertical lines
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

Wanted :

[image: Imgur]

Actual result:

[image: img]

Comment: Try setting the Y to NULL?

Comment: It's not possible, it tells me "replacement has length zero"

Comment: I mean during the plotting, some way to discard the results(kind of an invisible replacement?).

Comment: just plot with only the points that have y below 1000? (considering your data, that should be quite simple: takes x from min to max prior to corresponding y above 1000, then add the end of your curve (with `lines`) by taking first x with y under 1000 till max x

Comment: Try this: `data.frame(x= x,y= y) %>% 
  mutate(y=ifelse(y==0,NA,y)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+geom_point()` or simply filter everything not equal to 0. Used tidyverese for convenience.

Comment: @Cath It works but I then need to know the x where to cut my data, I gave this function as an example but with a more complex data it may become time consuming

Comment: @NelsonGon It works with point but if I want to have lines, using geom_line() will create a plateau

Comment: x[which(y>1000)[1]-1] ?

Comment: This only gives me the first value for x, if y goes back and forth above and under 1000, it's not going to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
x <- seq(from=-50,to=50,by=0.1)
y<--x^2+2500
ylims <- range(y)
plot(x,y,type="l",ylim = ylims)
```

[image]

```r
y[y>1000]<-NA
plot(x,y,type="l", ylim = ylims)
```

[image]

```r
## tidyverse ====
x <- seq(from=-50,to=50,by=0.1)
y<--x^2+2500
library(tidyverse)

p <- tibble(x,y) %>%
  mutate(yCutoff = ifelse(y>1000, NA, y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = yCutoff)) +
  ylim(range(y)) +
  theme_minimal()
p
```

[image]

```r
# your x-Values:
p$data  %>% filter(is.na(yCutoff))%>% select(x)
#> # A tibble: 775 x 1
#>        x
#>    <dbl>
#>  1 -38.7
#>  2 -38.6
#>  3 -38.5
#>  4 -38.4
#>  5 -38.3
#>  6 -38.2
#>  7 -38.1
#>  8 -38  
#>  9 -37.9
#> 10 -37.8
#> # … with 765 more rows
```